# Japanese dictionary for mathematics/computer science jargon

Tags: resources, terminology, dictionary, computing, mathematics

I study mathematics and computer science, and I'm starting to learn japanese. Could you suggest me dictionaries/sites/etc where I could learn terminology on these subjects?

Comment: OFF TOPIC: Not exactly about Japanese language per se, but more so about finding references for Japanese.

Comment: See [this question](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1/can-this-site-include-questions-about-resources-one-would-use-to-learn-the-japane) on meta; I think the jury's still out on what constitutes an on-topic resource question.  FWIW, I think this one is valid.

Comment: thanx amanda, i actually just saw this question float back up to top on meta. so i'm going to remove the off-topic (if i can). Apparantly, i can't remove my vote to close.  But according to the consensus, this seems to be on topic.  Sorry for the confusion _|-|o

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[EDICT](http://www.edrdg.org/cgi-bin/wwwjdic/wwwjdic?1C) (which is the corpus JquickTrans apparently uses) has several special dictionaries for technical terms.  The "Computing/Telecomms" dictionary includes such wonderful words as:

変数設定 【へんすうせってい】 (n) variable initialization
参照渡し 【さんしょうわたし】 (n) call by reference
オブジェクト[指向]{しこう}プログラミング  (n) object-oriented programming

Answer (score 5):

It is a little bit informal, but the language site that I always use to look up some word in Japanese is [alc.co.jp](http://eow.alc.co.jp)

It uses the Eijiro dictionary, and has pretty good coverage on many subjects.

Hope this helps.

Comment: One of my japanese colleage use it

Comment: @YOU Yes, this service is very popular among the Japanese. Combined with a plugin like rikaikun or rikaichan it is an essential everyday tool for my work.

Answer (score 3):

If you are not a computer nerd, but want to know academically, I think [岩波数学辞典](http://www.amazon.co.jp/%E5%B2%A9%E6%B3%A2%E6%95%B0%E5%AD%A6%E8%BE%9E%E5%85%B8-%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E6%95%B0%E5%AD%A6%E4%BC%9A/dp/4000803093) is the standard for mathematics.

Comment: It's so expensive, though, and the reviews don't indicate its scope (abstract math? applied math? graduate level?)

Answer (score 2):

I have been using [JquickTrans](http://www.postmeta.com/) dictionary software for years (had to pay $15 before but it's freeware now), and it has a few specialized dictionary catalogs that could be useful to find science and math terms:

[image: FFT]

[image: REGEX]

[image: EXP]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about math, but at my company, (where i am the only english speaker) everyone understands the katakana versions of the english words without even knowing english.  If you come to japan though, there are actually tons of Japanese dictionaries specifically for programming terms.

Answer (score 1):

I always check [Weblio's dictionary](http://ejje.weblio.jp/) for a lot of great real-world examples of technical terms. I haven't looked into what the sources are exactly, but they seem to have a lot of technical corpora that I haven't seen anywhere else.