# Written resources for scientific and philosophic japanese?

Tags: resources, terminology, dictionary

In this [Question about computer science jargon](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/698/japanese-dictionary-for-mathematics-computer-science-jargon), most answers to date are electronic resources and that makes sense.

But I would like to know if there are printed japanese/english or japanese/german dictionary which gives careful consideration to scientific, technological and philosophical (analytical, epistemology) meanings of kanjis without being too difficult to peruse for a non-native learner. I would not be able to comfortably use a japanese-only reference.

It does not need to be strictly a dictionary. I am interested in printed books about scientific japanese writing for instance, or specialized documents with a glossary for that specialty. I remember among other things seing a japanese colleague with a nice book about german philosophical concepts and their kanji approximation and translation. I presume there are other such books in areas such as biology, cognitive sciences, physics, history of science.

Comment: I can't help you with printed resources, but a trick I often use to translate a technical term is looking at the Japanese Wikipedia page that's linked to the English page.  For instance, the English page on [existentialism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existentialism) links to a Japanese page entitled [実存主義](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%AE%9F%E5%AD%98%E4%B8%BB%E7%BE%A9), hence I am fairly confident that 実存主義 is the word for existentialism.  This isn't a great answer, but it's better than nothing.

Comment: It is a nice trick, nevertheless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~jwb/cgi-bin/wwwjdic.cgi?1C has many dictionaries, including some scientific ones.

But you asked for print media...

- Computer Terms - [English-Japanese / Japanese-English Dictionary of Computer and Data-Processing Terms](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0262061147)
- Chemical & Science - [Japanese-English Chemical Dictionary: Including a Guide to Japanese Patents and Scientific Literature](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3527312935)
- Science and Technical Terms - [Japanese/English - English/Japanese Glossary of Scientific and Technical Terms](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471574635)

There are others, too.  Searching Amazon for "japanese english dictionary scientific" is a good start.

Thanks to the rules here, 2 of those don't get linked.  You'll have to copy and paste.

Answer (score 3):

Books:
Basic Technical Japanese by Edward Daub, et.al
Intermediate Technical Japanese

Search for "Technical Japanese Series" on amazon or google. There are books that cover specific science/engineering areas.