# What is the correct reading for べき乗打切り待機法?

Tags: readings

On [this page](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%B9%E3%81%8D%E4%B9%97%E6%89%93%E5%88%87%E3%82%8A%E5%BE%85%E6%A9%9F%E6%B3%95), different readings are give in different dictionaries for べき乗打切り待機法: べき**のり**うちきりたいきほう in JMDict and ベキ**ジョウ**ウチキリタイキホウ in コンピューター用語辞典. The English translation given in both dictionaries are the same: "truncated binary exponential back-off".

Which of these readings is correct? Or, if they are both correct, can they be used interchangeably?

I know the べき乗 for exponent is read as べきじょう. Where does the reading べきのり come from?

Note: I don't actually use the word, nor do I understand its exact meaning. I saw it on [this answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/699/903). I know べき乗 is read as べきじょう, which means exponential, so I thought the reading in the answer was wrong. I tried to find out what it actually means, but search results from the internet are mostly dictionary results. Most of the readings given are べき**のり**うちきりたいきほう.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[冪乗](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?p=%E5%86%AA%E4%B9%97&stype=1&dtype=0) (“power” or “powering” in mathematics; often written as べき乗 because “冪” is not a 常用漢字) is read as べきじょう.  Reading it as べきのり is wrong.  Moreover, translating “truncated binary exponential back-off” as べき乗打切り待機法 is also incorrect (where did “binary” go?).

I think that “exponential back-off” is usually translated as 指数バックオフ or 指数的バックオフ.  I do not know a standard translation of “truncated binary exponential back-off.”

> Where does the reading べきのり come from?

JMDict contains many errors.  This is just one of them.  And an error in a “dictionary” spreads out quickly because many pages are automatically generated from the underlying data of JMDict.

Comment: I think the wrong translation should be the reason why I didn't find any description of the method on the internet.